# How can I vectorize the following python code (image transition)?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I just started to learn vectorizing methods and it's still hard for me to get used to it. I want to make an image transition effect using OpenCV and NumPy. As a first step I just cut the images together diagonally, without caring about blending effect.

```
im3 = np.zeros(im1.shape, np.uint8)

yMax = int(im1.shape[0])
xMax = int(im1.shape[1])
border = (xMax+yMax)/2

for y in range(yMax):
    for x in range(xMax):
        if((y + x) > border):
            im3[y , x, :] = im1[y, x, :]
        else:
            im3[y, x, :] = im2[y, x, :]
```

(where im1 and im2 is two previously read bgr images with the same size)

But I know it's really slow using for loop so I wanted to use vectorized methods. As a next step I moved the if else.

```
for y in range(yMax):
    for x in range(xMax):  
        im3[y, x, :] =  im1[y, x, :] * ((y + x) > border)
        im3[y, x, :] += im2[y, x, :] * ((y + x) < border)
```

But then I realized I still can't see the way to get rid of the for loops because even if I can change

```
imx[y, x, :] to imx[ :, :, :]
```

I still need the x and y in:

```
((y + x) > border)
```

I'm almost sure there's some really easy way to do this or I'm using a wrong method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure you're doing what you think your doing, but naively, this is how you'd do it:

```
im3 = np.where(np.indices(im1.shape[:2]).sum(0)[:, :, None] > border, im1, im2)
```

`np.indices(im1.shape[:2]).sum(0)` is just the `x + y` part without doing the `for` loop, and `where` lets you assign all as one step based on whether `x + y > border` is `True` (`im1`) or False (`im2`).

Comment: Yeah, I'm not quite sure either, I'm just experimenting with things.
At first I've got an error:
"ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1704,2272) (1704,2272,3) (1704,2272,3) "

But if I separate the channels it works
im3[:,:,0] = np.where((np.indices(im1.shape[:2]).sum(0) > border), im1[:,:,0], im2[:,:,0]) ect.

So thanks!

Comment: think I fixed the broadcasting issue, check now.